# Sorting points clockwise given triangulated mesh

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, mesh

Given a triangulated mesh (no self intersection, no holes, possibly concave) represented as an unordered list of triangles (list of 3 vertices) **or** rectangles (list of 4 vertices), i.e.

```
[
    [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]],
    [[x4, y4], [x5, y5], [x6, y6], [x7, y7],
    ....
]
```

How can I sort the vertices in a clockwise order?

Answer (score 0):

You can [sort by angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187184/c-sorting-2d-points-clockwise).

There are different implementations, like you can use `atan2()` in C++ to calculate the angle of each vertex and sort them along.

In case they have same angle, you can sort them by distance to the origin to break tie.