# Sort 2D points counter clockwise

Tags: c++, sorting, 2d, points, convex

My question is related to this one: [c++ Sorting 2D Points clockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187184/c-sorting-2d-points-clockwise/39187213#39187213), but somehow that solution doesn't work for me. I am trying to sort 4 2d points counter clockwise.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct p {
float x,y;
} Point;

double getClockwiseAngle(Point p) {
double angle = 0.0;

angle = atan2(p.x, -p.y);
return angle;
}

bool comparePoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
     return getClockwiseAngle(p1) < getClockwiseAngle(p2);
}

int main() {
    ...
    sort(givenPoints.begin(), givenPoints.end(), comparePoints);
    ...
}
```

Example: 
Input (-4, 2), (1, 4), (0,1), (-1, 4)

Output (-4, 2), (-1, 4), (1, 4), (0,1)

Comment: The answer is using `-atan2`.  You are using `atan2`.  See the difference?

Comment: Yup, you're right, but the output it's still wrong, it's just that now the points are incorrectly sorted clockwise, instead of counter clockwise.

Comment: Well, that is what you copied.  If you don't change anything it wont sort differently.  You probably need to change `getClockwiseAngle(p1) < getClockwiseAngle(p2)` to `getClockwiseAngle(p1) > getClockwiseAngle(p2)`

Comment: Changing what you told me just brings me to my original output. You're basically moving a '-' from one place to another.

Comment: [Looks like it works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e3088b71ae0c861)

Comment: @NathanOliver If you add `(0,1)` it will probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there were 2 negative signs that needed to be fixed as indicated in the comment.  This seems to work:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

typedef struct p {
    float x,y;
} Point;

double getClockwiseAngle(Point p) {
    double angle = 0.0;

    angle = -1 * atan2(p.x, -1 * p.y);
    return angle;
}

bool comparePoints(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return getClockwiseAngle(p1) < getClockwiseAngle(p2);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> givenPoints{{-4,2}, {1,4}, {0,1}, {-1,4}};
    sort(givenPoints.begin(), givenPoints.end(), comparePoints);
    std::cout << "Sorted Points: ";

    for(auto it = givenPoints.begin(); it != givenPoints.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << "(" << it->x << ", " << it->y << ")" ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
Sorted Points: (0, 1)(1, 4)(-4, 2)(-1, 4)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up implementing it, but it's still not outputing the wright answer. The correct is (0, 1), (1, 4), (-1, 4), (-4, 2). Neither, your program, nor mine outputs this result.

Comment: Moving clockwise around the circle, (-4,2) comes before (-1,4).  Draw it out on a piece of graph paper.  The program is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- To sort the points starting from 12 o’clock, counterclockwise, you first have to [**rotate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions) them -90degrees (12 o’clock becomes 3 o’clock):

  ```
  x’ = y
  y’ = -x
  ```
- [`atan2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) is using arguments **signs to compute the quadrant**. The following lines are not equivalent:

  ```
  bool b = atan2(0.0, 1.0) < atan2(0.0, -1.0); // true
  bool b = atan2(-0.0, 1.0) < atan2(-0.0, -1.0); // false
  ```

  Therefore you cannot use `atan2` to sort the points.

Instead of `atan2( -x, y)` try `atan2( x == .0f ? .0f : -x, y )` - **not tested**.

Comment: atan() or atan2() seem to be way too expensive. A simple y/x should do the trick. Different cases for positive, zero and negative x must be implemented though.